# Flutter APK download from external server

Tags: flutter

I need to show updater screen to user every time new version released.

For Android, need to show two button, one for play store download button and one for apk download from external.
For iOS, only a button to download from app store.

1. how can I check, if there is new version released.
2. how to download and automatically install apk on android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

new_version: ^0.3.0

[new_version](https://pub.dev/packages/new_version)

> New Version Plugin  # A Flutter plugin that makes it possible to:
>
> Check if a user has the most recent version of your app installed.
> Show the user an alert with a link to the appropriate app store page.